# Compare 2 lines and print column numbers if matching and NULL if not

Tags: unix, awk

for below scenario i need ur help.

File 1: Is a config file
a|b|c|d|e|f|g

File 2: Input file
a|c|d|g

I have to compare "File 1" and "File 2" and print the following from file 2

a||c|d|||g

So basically I need to compare both the records and for the matching records i have to print it from file 2 and when not matching i have to put NULLS.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post more clear samples of input and output in code tags in your post.

Comment: Does each file just contain the single line/record or are there many? If there are many is line 1 of file1 compared to JUST line1 of file2 or does each line need to look for a match in the other file based on some criteria?

Comment: @JNevill - File 1 will have one record only. File 2 will have many records. So I have to compare File 1 with first record in File 2 and generate and awk command that can print the output i require

Comment: @royal23enfield, request you to please post sample of input and output more clearly.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13
File 1 - it is a configuration file and has only the header.
File 2 - Input file. It contains multiple lines along with header.
Requirement: Compare the header from File 1 with File 2 and if any column is missing NULLS need to be appended in the File 2 data. So my idea is to use awk and print the file 2. For that i need to compare both files and generate like below:
awk '{print $1,NULL,£2}' < file 2

Comment: What's the output when file2 is `g|d|c|a`?

Comment: @royal23enfield, please post them in your post, comments are not meant for posting questions, kindly do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can interpret what you're asking: you want to "remap" File2 onto the headers of File1.

```
$ cat File1
first|last|email|phone|address|colour|size

$ cat File2
first|last|phone|size
Glenn|Jackman|555-555-1212|L

$ awk -F '|' '
      NR == FNR {
          n = NF
          for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) head[i] = $i
          print
          next
      }
      FNR == 1 {
          for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) f2head[i] = $i
          next
      }
      {
          for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) data[f2head[i]] = $i
          for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
              printf "%s%s", data[head[i]], (i<n ? FS : RS)
      }
  ' File1 File2

first|last|email|phone|address|colour|size
Glenn|Jackman||555-555-1212|||L
```

From the first block, the `head` array will be:

```
{1:"first",2:"last",3:"email",4:"phone",5:"address",6:"colour",7:"size"}
```

From the second block, the `f2head` array will be:

```
{1:"first",2:"last",3:"phone",4:"size"}
```

In the third block, the `data` array will be

```
{"first":"Glenn","last":"Jackman","phone":"555-555-1212","size":"L"}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i will check and let u know

Comment: thanks for the code. Can you please provide an explanation on how the code works? Im a beginner and not able to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}; 
       NR==1 {n=split($0,ht); 
              for(i=1;i<=n;i++) h[ht[i]]=i; next} 
       NR==2 {n2=split($0,h2)}  
             {split($0,t); $0=""; 
              for(i=1;i<=n2;i++) $(h[h2[i]])=t[i]}1' file1 file2
```

seems cryptic but in essence does the following:

> find the index of header2 (`h2`) values in header1 (`h`) and set the corresponding field (`$(h[h2[i]])`) in from file2 (`t[i]`).